# Android QuickBlox updating online status

Tags: android, chat, quickblox

I'm using user.getLastRequestAt to determine if user online. But this field updates only when user is sending messages or performing login etc.

I also send presence periodically to remain available via startAutoSendPresence() method. But it doesn't update LastRequestAt field.

Is there any way to implement online-status cheking? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, field **LastRequestAt** is updated after any requests to REST API.

But QuickBlox team released an update for Chat module - so now it also works for Chat presence. Please try.

Comment: Hm... It didn't work on friday but after your answer it does. And i have changed nothing. Now I'm really receiving updated field lastRequestAt... Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share the code.. How can I update lastRequestAt() time.

Comment: it's updated automatically after each API request and each chat presence

Comment: @IgorKhomenko can you provide any link about this assumption? I'm using QuickBox for Android and the LastRequestAt field is only updated when my users perform login. Thanks!